# get function execution context

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function `foo`:

```
function foo() {
   return 'foo';
}
```

While `foo` got executed is there a way to know if `foo` was called inside object declaration ? I want to distinguish these two cases:

```
var bar = {
   prop1: foo()
}

var var1 = foo();
```

Comment: The language does not make that information available. You'd have to design your function with a parameter or something.

Comment: If you're trying to implement class-like methods, ES6 now has [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that are intended for that purpose (where `this` refers to the object instead of Window when not explicitly rebound).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach demonstrating the suggestions in the comments and assuming you'd rather call `bar.prop1` instead of `bar.prop1()`.

```js
function foo (ctx) {
  console.log(ctx == window)
  return 'foo'
}

class Bar {
  get prop1() {
    return foo(this)
  }
}

var var1 = foo(this);

var bar = new Bar();
bar.prop1;
```